# SQL - Subquery in Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, northwind

I'm using the northwind database to refresh my SQL skills by creating some more or less complex queries. Unfortunately I could not find a solution for my last use case:
"Get the sum of the five greatest orders for every category in year 1997."

The tables involved are:

```
Orders(OrderId, OrderDate)
Order Details(OrderId, ProductId, Quantity, UnitPrice)
Products(ProductId, CategoryId)
Categories(CategoryId, CategoryName)
```

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, SUM(
  (SELECT TOP 5 od2.UnitPrice*od2.Quantity 
   FROM [Order Details] od2, Products p2
   WHERE od2.ProductID = p2.ProductID
   AND c.CategoryID = p2.CategoryID
   ORDER BY 1 DESC))
FROM [Order Details] od, Products p, Categories c, Orders o 
WHERE od.ProductID = p. ProductID
AND p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
AND od.OrderID = o.OrderID
AND YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 1997
GROUP BY c.CategoryName
```

Well... It turned out that subqueries are not allowed in aggregate functions. I've read other posts about this issue but could not find a solution for my specific use case. Hope you can help me out...

Comment: Which version of RDBMS are you using? Also your question is not correct because the order can belong in more than one category.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2012. If you refer to the subquery, there is a WHERE clause - `WHERE c.categoryID = p2.CategoryID` - that should filter for one category only.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Subqueries are not generally allowed in aggregate functions.  Instead, move the aggregate *inside* the subquery.  In this case, you'll need an extra level of subquery because of the `top 5`:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName,
  (select sum(val)
   from (SELECT TOP 5 od2.UnitPrice*od2.Quantity as val
         FROM [Order Details] od2, Products p2
         WHERE od2.ProductID = p2.ProductID
         AND c.CategoryID = p2.CategoryID
         ORDER BY 1 DESC
        ) t
  )
FROM [Order Details] od, Products p, Categories c, Orders o 
WHERE od.ProductID = p. ProductID
AND p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
AND od.OrderID = o.OrderID
AND YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 1997
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, c.CategoryId
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job! Just for info... the CategoryID needs to be grouped as well. The last line should look like `GROUP BY c.CategoryName, c.CategoryID`. But thanks for your time, that query looks really weird to me. Need to analyze it in depth now... :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function instead of excessive subquery.

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT c.CategoryName, od2.UnitPrice, od2.Quantity,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.CategoryName ORDER BY od2.UnitPrice * od2.Quantity DESC) AS rn
  FROM [Order Details] od JOIN Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
                          JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
                          JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
  WHERE o.OrderDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, '19970101'), 0)
    AND o.OrderDate < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, '19970101')+1, 0)
  )
  SELECT CategoryName, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) AS val
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn < 6
  GROUP BY CategoryName
```

Answer (score 3):

Its definitely a sub query problem here is an [excellent article](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html) on this (originally written for Access but the syntax is identical), also orderdate = 1997 will give order date for 1 jan 1997' -- you need datepart(year, orderdate) = 1997, once you have the (up to five) rows returned for each category you can then encapsulate the rows returned and agregate them

Comment: Thanks for the link. You're right I edited my post. It should be ofc `YEAR(o.OrderDate) = '1997'`

Comment: Could you provide an example for "encapsulate the rows returned and aggregate them"?

Comment: SELECT x.A, x.B, x.C, SUM(x.d) AS D FROM ( Any valid sql select statement containing columns a, b , c, d, e) x GROUP BY x.d

Comment: This is also a sub query, however its a very simple one and the top 5 grouped by Category subquery is a more advanced and powerful use. I did not want to confuse by using the same descriptive nown. More important for you to be aware of the full power of sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem with an Access subquery where the records were sorted by date.  When I used the "Last" aggregate function I found it passed through all of the subqueries and retrieved the last row of data from the Access table, and not the sorted query as intended. Although I could have rewritten the query to use the aggregate function within the first set of parenthesis (as was previously suggested) I found it easier to save query results as a table in the database sorted in the order I wanted and then use the "Last" aggregate function to retrieve the values I wanted.  I'll run an update query in the future to keep results current.  Not efficient but effective.